# Class Cast Exception... expandable listview to text view

Tags: android

I'm getting a classcastexception on line 59 of one of my classes.  The log says I'm trying to cast an expandable listview to a text view.  Here's the log

```
02-17 18:56:13.165    1013-1013/com.psesto.journeysend E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ExpandableListView cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
            at com.psesto.journeysend.SmsStatusAdapter.getView(SmsStatusAdapter.java:59)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2177)
            at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1247)
            at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1159)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:698)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:494)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2189)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1905)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1104)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1284)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and here's line SmsStatusAdapter getView and ViewHolder methods :

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sms_status_list_item, null);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_sms_status);
            viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_sms_status_icon);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {

            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.textView.setText(getStatusText()); // this is line 59
        viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(getImage());

        return convertView;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {

        TextView textView;
        ImageView imageView;
    }
```

Here is sms_status_list_item.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_sms_status"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:text="Status"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_sms_status_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Let me know any other code you need and I'll put it right up.  Thanks in advance

Comment: can u please put your xml used in the get view function

Comment: @PulkitSethi  Coming right up!

Comment: @youssefhassan already tried that

Comment: clean ur solution and try again this happens sometimes nothing wrong with the code

Comment: @youssefhasson doing it now, give me 3 min

Comment: @youssefhassan that worked... why

Comment: Sometimes the compiler get stucked in the xml so by swapping the views you forced it to recompile that file. I will post the comment as an answer to help others

Comment: once you do, you get the check fine sir :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can swap the views(textview and imageview) in your xml as sometimes the compiler gets stucked and can't see the changes you did for the xml file.